# How to receive the users data from ipregistry api

Tags: javascript, html, api, ip-address

I'm using https://ipregistry.co api , its an ip address api that collects the ip's from users who entered a website.

Now I have already integrated it into my website, and its working properly and everything is good but the problem is i dont know where im going to receive the data.

By the way I'm using html and javascript.

```html
<script> src="https://unpkg.com/@ipregistry/client/dist/browser/index.js">
</script>

<script>
    const client = new ipregistry.IpregistryClient('THE_KEY');
    client.lookup('73.2.2.2').then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.err(error);
    });
</script>
```

scscs

Comment: The website says it provides "IP GeoLocation and Threat Detection", it doesn't say anything about it being an external "database" for you to store data into and retrieve it back.

Comment: I didn't notice that  so do you know any tool that will do what I want?

Comment: What is it that you _want_?

Comment: Im trying to find a way to get users ip addres when they enter my website and get it inserted automatically into my database.   But i dont know how .